# Unable to extract whole cookie with Python's requests module

Tags: python, web-scraping, networking, cookies, request

I want to make crawler for one website that requires login.
I have email and password (sorry but I can not share it)

This is the website:
https://www.eurekalert.org/
When I click on login, it redirects me here:
https://signin.aaas.org/oxauth/login

First I have done this:

```
session = requests.session()

r = session.get('https://www.eurekalert.org/')
cookies = r.cookies.get_dict()
#cookies = cookies['PHPSESSID']
print("COOKIE eurekalert", cookies)
```

The only cookie that I could get is:

```
{'PHPSESSID': 'vd2jp35ss5d0sm0i5em5k9hsca'}
```

But for logging in I need more cookie key-value pairs.

I have managed to log in, but for logging in I need to have cookie data, and I can not retrieve it:

```
login_response = session.post('https://signin.aaas.org/oxauth/login', headers=login_headers, data=login_data)

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.eurekalert.org',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'referer': 'https://signin.aaas.org/',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'cookie': '_fbp=fb.1.1626615735334.1262364960; __gads=ID=d7a7a2d080319a5d:T=1626615735:S=ALNI_MYdVrKc4-uasMo3sVMCjzFABP0TeQ; __utmz=28029352.1626615736.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=28029352.223995016.1626615735.1626615735.1626615735.1; _ga=GA1.2.223995016.1626615735; adBlockEnabled=not%20blocked; _gid=GA1.2.109852943.1629792860; AMCVS_242B6472541199F70A4C98A6%40AdobeOrg=1; AMCV_242B6472541199F70A4C98A6%40AdobeOrg=-1124106680%7CMCIDTS%7C18864%7CMCMID%7C62442014968131466430435549466681355333%7CMCAAMLH-1630397660%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1630397660%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1629800060s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.2.0; s_cc=true; __atuvc=2%7C31%2C0%7C32%2C0%7C33%2C1%7C34; PHPSESSID=af75g985r6eccuisu8dvkkv41v; s_tp=1616; s_ppv=www.eurekalert.org%2C58%2C58%2C938',
}

response = session.get('https://www.eurekalert.org/reporter/home', headers=headers)
print(response)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
```

The headers (full cookie data) are collected with `network->copy->copy curl->pasted here:`https://curl.trillworks.com/

But values that should go in the `cookie` should be retrieved dynamically. Im missing the value that should go in the `'cookie'`.
When I go in the cookie tab, all values are there, but I can not get it with my request.